# winforms webbrowser control shows a simple text in 3 lines

Tags: webbrowser-control

Trying to use a webbrowser control instead of label control for showing html in winforms page. I'm feeding it with a line as simple as

```
<span style='font-family:symbol;'>a</span>
```

and the result is shown like first line blank, then alpha, then another line blank. How to solve this?